# How to write a PDF editor?

Tags: c#, c++, pdf

How would you write a PDF editor in C++ or C#?

Would you recommend any PDF libraries, such as a PDF visual editing toolkit?

Comment: I wouldn't - PDFs are a god-awful mess.

Comment: That's a hugely broad question.  You might need to be more specific.  It's like asking "How do I write a game?".  Only answer is "it depends".

Comment: Unless you're trying to accomplish something specific or are deliberately inflicting Anguishing Pain on yourself, I recommend turning the other way and RUNNING.  What about PDFs do you want to edit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of libraries that can help you, See [iText](http://itextpdf.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you have a look at PDFedit if you want see what is possible in a PDF editor and what is under the hood in PDF. I wrote an introductory blog about it at http://www.jpedal.org/PDFblog/2010/09/useful-pdf-tools-pdfedit/

Answer (score 0):

You can actually write your own editor for annotations using incremental approach mentioned in PDF document 1.7 .