# creating a pdf editor like application in c#

Tags: c#-4.0, pdf-generation, itext

I want to create a desktop application, whose functioning is as follows :
1. user opens a pdf file in the form
2. then, it gets opened up on the UI. After that, user performs certain editing using mouse 
   like drawing a rectangle, crossing a certain region (similar to paint)
3. Then, after doing all the editing, he saves that file into another pdf (edited one)

I am doing it in c#. Can you suggest, how to do it ?

Comment: This question is several magnitudes too broad. This site is for concrete questions.

Answer (score 2):

This may get handy,

[How to write a PDF editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215844/how-to-write-a-pdf-editor)

iText ® is a library that allows you to create and manipulate PDF documents. It enables developers looking to enhance web- and other applications with dynamic PDF document generation and/or manipulation.
Developers can use iText to:

```
Serve PDF to a browser
Generate dynamic documents from XML files or databases
Use PDF's many interactive features
Add bookmarks, page numbers, watermarks, etc.
Split, concatenate, and manipulate PDF pages
Automate filling out of PDF forms
Add digital signatures to a PDF file
```

iText is available in Java as well as in C#.

PDFsharp is the Open Source library that easily creates PDF documents from any .NET language.
The same drawing routines can be used to create PDF documents, draw on the screen, or send output to any printer.

```
It can use either GDI+ or WPF.
It includes support for Unicode in PDF files.
```

It also includes MigraDoc Foundation which brings you all the high-level functionality not included in PDFsharp.